# What are some examples of ordered data?

Tags: data-mining, data, data-cleaning

Tan,Steinbech,Kumar's book says

> For some types of data, attributes have relationships that involve order in time or space.

I want some real life examples of such data, can you provide me. I couldn't find anything in google so asking here.

Here is what is written in a ppt.

I couldn't make much sense of that as well.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FW84y.jpg

I have found another definition which is somewhat easier to grasp. Is this correct? And can you send me some examples of this?

> Ordered data is when data is collected over time.

Source-:https://variation.com/wp-content/distribution_analyzer_help/hs147.htm

References-:
[https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~kumar001/dmbook/slides/chap2_data.pdf](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Ekumar001/dmbook/slides/chap2_data.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

There are many real-world examples. Time series is the most common one: the observations are ordered by time. Exam grades are another example, e.g. A>B>C>D...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be any kind of data that can be organized in a logical way.

For example, bills that includes creation date or location (= that could be translated to a X,Y geographical position), or a employee ID in a company that is a number incremented with every new employee, or any name that could be classified in an alphabetical order.

In your example, the data is primarily ordered by Item, and then Event.